# rspec-rails: testing a controller action that renders a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, partials

I have a UsersController that has `index` and `new` actions.  I use haml, the index haml file contains the following code:

```
= link_to 'Add User', new_user_path, { :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 
  'data-target' => '#modal-window', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right' }
```

So when the user clicks 'Add User' the `_new.html.haml` partial is presented to the user as a modal.  It works great.  Here's the new action in the controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Now in my controller spec I am trying to do the following:

```
describe "new action" do
  before do
    get 'new'
  end

  # specs for 'new' action go here
end
```

However that gives an error

```
Failure/Error: get 'new'
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template users/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
     * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007faa44b03218>"
```

Presumably because it can't find `new.html.haml` which of course doesn't exist because the file is a partial named `_new.html.haml`.  What is the correct syntax for `get`ting the partial?  If not, how can I test the `new` action?

Comment: Shouldn't your controller be rendering a view?

Comment: @LeoCorrea Good point.  I changed the ```format.html``` to ```format.html { render :partial => 'new' }``` and it worked.  Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think that was my answer :). You found it on your own. You could answer your own question and mark it as correct. Glad you were able to find the answer.

Comment: Okay, then.  Thanks for commenting, if I hadn't found it I'm sure the comment would've done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what I changed in the new action to make it work:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :partial => 'new' }
  format.js
end
```

When the app is running rails figures out to render the partial, but I guess it needs to be explicit for rspec.  If there are better ways to do it I'd be glad to hear them.